# Jmeter variable to be used in jruby preprocessor

Tags: jmeter, jruby

In my jmeter script i am extracting the session key using the regular expression extractor. I want to use this extracted variable inside a jruby JSR223 preprocessor. I have a part of my jruby script that i want to put the extracted variable ${key} into the jruby variable of key

key = ${key}

I need to put the exctracted session key into the key variable. In the ruby script this fails. Anybody know what i need in ruby to pull in the extracted variable?

Comment: I was reading through the docs for JMeter. Did you try syntax like _vars.get("VAR1"); vars.put("VAR2","value"); vars.remove("VAR3");_ ?

Answer (score 0):

According to my rudimentary knowledge of Ruby and mostly to [Calling Java from JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby) guide your code should look something like:

```
key = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().get("key")
```

Just in case you want a little bit extended version:

```
# Declare shorthands to JMeter API methods
vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
log = org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass()

# Get the value of key JMeter Variable and put it into key Ruby variable
key = vars.get("key")
# Print key variable to jmeter.log file
log.info("key=" + key)
```

[image: JRuby accessing Variables]

---

Be aware that if you plan to use the script, you're working on for conducting high loads it's better to reconsider the choice of the scripting language. It is recommended to use [Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) language. Well-developed Groovy scripts can be compiled into bytecode while scripts produced in other languages are being interpreted. Check out [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for more information and scripting best practices.